# How Do I Use FDT To Test An AIR App On A Mobile Device?

Tags: flash, air, fdt

Following the FDT tutorials and all is well, until I try to test the project on a device.

I can run the swf in an external window, it's the .SWF from the tutorial that makes
randomly colored circles. It works.(The tutorial fails to declare the 'size' variable,
might confuse people.)

But, I can't seem to figure out how to run the project on a device, since the icons the
tutorial-guy clicks on (when creating the project originally) are different than the icons
I have in my version of FDT. Also, when he chooses 'run as' he gets to choose his device,
where I don't have those options.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a tutorial on how You can use the FDT 5.6 AIR for iOS Project Template. Hope is detailed enough to set You on the right path.

Here is the link:

[.SWFGEEK - Using FDT 5.6 AIR for iOS Project Template](http://www.swfgeek.net/2012/10/17/using-fdt-5-6-air-for-ios-project-template/)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials on the site are outdated, that is why it will seem a little confusing.

To test on device, you simply run an 'FDT AIR Application' configuration, choose the platform and if it's a mobile platform (e.g. Android or iOS) then you will see the option to test on device.

[image]

The next screen to pop up....
[image]